# Navigating to a new view from an action button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If we have a TabNavigator, StackNavigator, etc... or a combination of them, we can navigate from one scene to another.

I'm trying to navigate to a compose page using a floating action bar. I'm stuck at knowing what to pass for 'navigate' function.

```
<ActionButton.Item title="New Message" onPress={this.showMessageComposer.bind(this)} />

showMessageComposer(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('MessageCreator');
}
```

How can I navigate to a custom scene for which the navigation paths are not set elsewhere?

```
export default MessageCreator extends Component
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put the new View into a StackNavigator with other parent views so that the new view can be navigated to.

```
let HomeStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        HomeTabs: {
            screen: HomeTabs,
        },
        MessageComposer: {
            screen: MessageComposer
        }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
);
```